# On button press, play a video from network

Tags: flutter

I have a query, how to play a video from the network on click of a button.

I have tried some steps but didn't succeed. https://kalyaninform@bitbucket.org/kalyaninform/sunsetcastmedia.git

```
'onPressed: () {
   VideoPlayerScreen();
},'
```

I am trying to play the video from the network in full screen and after playback, the video screen should close and return to the app.

Comment: I tried to debug the app using the real device but, when i press the watch trailer, button nothing happens in the console or new page open for the video.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new VideoPlayerApp()),
    );
},
```

I solved the problem by  using the above code to navigate to the videoplayerPage view, which displayes the video along witha floating button.